# Submit a form which is in for loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

A form within for loop, in this form user add a excel file using input type file,

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
 <form id="TypeValidation" method="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" id="pii_categoryid" name="pii_categoryid" value="<?php echo $i;?>" /> 
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-rose btn-round btn-file">
        <span class="fileinput-new">Select File</span>
        <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
          <input type="file" name="<?php echo $i;?>_attachment" id="<?php echo $i;?>_attachment" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv" />
        </span>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-round fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove</a>
          <button type="submit" name="add_file" id="add_file" value="<?php echo $i;?>_file" class="btn btn-success btn-round fileinput-exists">Upload</button>
    </div>
 </form>    
}
```

This form is submit using jquery here is code

```
$("#TypeValidation").on('submit',(function(e) 
{ 
var pii_categoryid = $(this).find('input[name="pii_categoryid"]').val();
var fileUploadID = $(this).find('button[name="add_file"]').val();
        e.preventDefault(); 
   $.ajax({
        url: "fn_dsr_wizard_submit.php?submitid="+fileUploadID,
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        dataType: "html",    
        success: function (result) { 
        alert(result);
        //prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", result);
        location.reload();
        if(result=='1'){
            location.replace("ds_dashboard.php");
        }else {
            location.replace("ds_dashboard.php");               
        }
        }
    });   
    }
    ));
```

My form show like this [image: this]

When user add client excel file then it is submitted but issue is that when user add donor file or other except client excel then its not submitted.

Comment: you need an unique form ID.

Comment: I also add this in submit button for unique ID id="add_file<?php echo $i;?>" but its still not working

Comment: `<form class="TypeValidation" method="" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-piicategoryid="<?php echo $i;?>" data-file="<?php echo $i;?>_file" />`

Comment: using `$(".TypeValidation").on('submit',function(e) { e.preventDefault(); 
var pii_categoryid = $(this).data("piicategoryid"), fileUploadID = $(this).data("add_file");`

Comment: You need the unique ID on the ID attribute of the form, not on the submit button.

Answer (score -2):

Try assign different ID and add a class name for each form like:

```
<form id="TypeValidation<?php echo $i; ?>" class="my-form" method="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In javascript:

```
$(".my-form").on('submit',(function(e)  { ...
```